# notation for point estimation in "All of Statistics" by Larry Wasserman

Tags: maximum-likelihood, asymptotics, notation

I'm currently reading All of Statistics by Larry Wasserman. The question is about the Delta Method, page 160 in the pdf (I have a hard copy, there it's page 133). The authors defines $\hat{\theta}$ or $\hat{\theta}_n$ as notation for the point estimator of $\theta$. 
In the Delta Method theorem he states (I quote):

> If $\tau  = g(\theta)$" where $g$ is differential and $g(\theta)\neq0
> > $  then
>   $$\frac{\hat{\tau}_n-\tau}{\hat{\operatorname{se}}(\hat{\tau})} \to
> > N(0,1) $$ in distribution, where $\hat{\tau}_n = g(\hat{\theta}_n)$
>   and
>   $\hat{\operatorname{se}}(\hat{\tau}_n)=|g'(\hat{\theta})|\hat{\operatorname{se}}(\hat{\theta}_n)$.

Does the author really mean $|g'(\hat{\theta})| = |g'(\hat{\theta}_n)|$ etc? Why is he even mixing these up in the same expression? Is there any reason to do so?

Comment: Did you have the curiosity to check what is the [delta method entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_method) on Wikipedia? We could have then maybe escaped this question.

Comment: @Xi'an I suspect the source of confusion is the use of the estimate instead of the population parameter which is the method of Wikipedia.

Comment: @JohnK yes its not about the theorem, just the authors notation. The book was suggested to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it is a typo. It seems to me that the author uses the notation $\widehat{\theta}_n$ and $\widehat{\theta}$ interchangeably. The former just emphasizes the asymptotics. Recall that the mle is consistent and thus if $g(\theta)$ is continuous, by the [CMT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_mapping_theorem) the standard error is estimated consistently.

Answer (score 0):

I think that it's a typo. Also, strictly speaking, the standard error is in asymtotic sense and exact standard error is not equal to that value.

Comment: thanks for you anwser. Where do you see the "exact standard error" in his theorem? I just see approximated ones.

Comment: I am sypaying that the approximated one is asymptotic result.